# Получение данных XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

столкнулся с такой проблемой.

XML

```
 <table id="economicCalendarData" class="genTbl closedTbl ecoCalTbl persistArea">
  <tbody pageStartAt ="" >              
    <tr>
                <td colspan="9" class="theDay" id="theDay1528070400">Понедельник, 4 июня 2018 г.</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr id="eventRowId_75">
              <td class="first left">Весь день</td>
              <td class="flagCur left"><span title="Новая Зеландия" class="ceFlags New_Zealand float_lang_base_1" data-img_key="New_Zealand"></span></td>
              <td class="left textNum sentiment"><span class="bold" >Праздник</span></td>
              <td colspan="6" class="left event">Новая Зеландия - День рождения королевы</td>
            </tr>
                                <tr id="eventRowId_368054" class="js-event-item " event_attr_ID="209" data-event-datetime="2018/06/04 02:50:00">
                  <td class="first left time js-time"  title="">02:50</td>
                  <td class="left flagCur noWrap"><span title="Япония" class="ceFlags Japan" data-img_key="Japan"></span> JPY</td>
                  <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" title="Низкая волатильность" data-img_key="bull1"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td>
                  <td class="left event" title="Для получения дополнительной информации нажмите здесь"><a href="/economic-calendar/monetary-base-209" target="_blank">
                  Денежная база (г/г) </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="bold act greenFont event-368054-actual" title="Лучше ожидаемого" id="eventActual_368054">8,1%</td>
                  <td class="fore  event-368054-forecast " id="eventForecast_368054">7,4%</td>
                  <td class="prev blackFont  event-368054-previous" id="eventPrevious_368054"><span title="">7,8%</span></td>
                                      <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container "  data-name ="Денежная база" data-event-id="209" data-status-enabled="0">
                                              <span class="alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Создать уведомление" data-tooltip-alt="Уведомление активно"></span>
                                          </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="eventRowId_368055" class="js-event-item " event_attr_ID="345" data-event-datetime="2018/06/04 04:00:00">
                  <td class="first left time js-time"  title="">04:00</td>
                  <td class="left flagCur noWrap"><span title="Австралия" class="ceFlags Australia" data-img_key="Australia"></span> AUD</td>
                  <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" title="Низкая волатильность" data-img_key="bull1"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td>
                  <td class="left event" title="Для получения дополнительной информации нажмите здесь"><a href="/economic-calendar/mi-inflation-gauge-345" target="_blank">
                  Индикатор инфляции MI (м/м) </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="bold act blackFont event-368055-actual" title="" id="eventActual_368055">0,0%</td>
                  <td class="fore  event-368055-forecast " id="eventForecast_368055"></td>
                  <td class="prev blackFont  event-368055-previous" id="eventPrevious_368055"><span title="">0,5%</span></td>
                                      <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container "  data-name ="Индикатор инфляции MI" data-event-id="345" data-status-enabled="0">
                                              <span class="alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Создать уведомление" data-tooltip-alt="Уведомление активно"></span>
                                          </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="eventRowId_368058" class="js-event-item revised" event_attr_ID="385" data-event-datetime="2018/06/04 04:30:00">
                  <td class="first left time js-time"  title="">04:30</td>
                  <td class="left flagCur noWrap"><span title="Австралия" class="ceFlags Australia" data-img_key="Australia"></span> AUD</td>
                  <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" title="Низкая волатильность" data-img_key="bull1"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td>
                  <td class="left event" title="Для получения дополнительной информации нажмите здесь"><a href="/economic-calendar/anz-job-advertisements-385" target="_blank">
                  Количество объявлений о вакансиях ANZ (м/м) </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="bold act blackFont event-368058-actual" title="" id="eventActual_368058">1,5%</td>
                  <td class="fore  event-368058-forecast " id="eventForecast_368058"></td>
                  <td class="prev redFont  event-368058-previous" id="eventPrevious_368058"><span title="Пересмотрено с -0,2%">-0,3%</span></td>
                                      <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container "  data-name ="Количество объявлений о вакансиях ANZ" data-event-id="385" data-status-enabled="0">
                                              <span class="alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Создать уведомление" data-tooltip-alt="Уведомление активно"></span>
                                          </td>
                </tr>
  </tbody>
```

У меня получается получить данные id, даты. А вот подклассы(tr) td, они называются все class и только их значение разные, как именно по значениям, выходить на данный класс, и выбирать это значение ?

Подскажите, что делать. Куда копать. Что читать. Любая помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: `"/table/tbody/id"` - это что?

Comment: @Igor адрес. Как я понял это переход по классам

Comment: М-м-м! Компилируемые xpath-выражения! Ни разу их не встречал в чужом коде, только в своём. Мало кто о них знает. Впрочем, хоть они и работают быстрее обычных, но всё равно проигрывают простым свойствам XmlDocument и Linq2Xml.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Я почти добился своего. Теперь встрял в другой проблеме) Как только решу. Отвечу на этот вапрос

Comment: Зачем было удалять код?